# Don't show chart but yes it is generate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

display a pie chart by call ajax. The call ajax works, when I inspect page I see the div with many somethings, namely, It is not empty.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
```

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart', 'bar', 'table'],
  'language': 'es',
  callback: function() {
    $("#formDiarioango").submit(drawChart);
  }
});

function drawChart(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  // viene la petición ajax
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('action'),
    type: 'post',
    data: $(this).serialize(),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(rta) {

      // material en el mes
      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Material', 'cantidad'],
        ['Organico', rta.tipoMateriales["organico"]],
        ['Reciclable', rta.tipoMateriales["reciclable"]],
        ['No aprovechable', rta.tipoMateriales["noAprovechable"]]
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Tipo de materiales recolectados (Kg) en el mes'
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('tipo_material_mes'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
  });
}
```

The div is empty  before of call with ajax, it has content later of the call, but does not show anything apart from the title of the graph and inspecting the code has something inside [as seen in the attached image].

[image]

But the web page does not show the chart but the title that I put on it

Some idea, suggestion to solve my problem I will be very grateful. I'm sorry for my English

Comment: You have `display: none` for the div that holds  `options` hashdata your from Ajax.

Comment: No, I dont do. My div is:  
    <div id="tipo_material_mes"></div>

Comment: Your `options` variable contains "Tipo de materiales recolectados (Kg) en el mes" text and your hidden div as shown in your screenshot contains the same text. So if this text is what you are missing, the problem is with `display: none`